# Динамическое изменение python-скрипта

Tags: python

Неизвестно зачем это нужно, но можно ли каким-то образом обращаться к тексту python скрипта во время его же исполнения из него самого?  Что-то вроде пишем код во время исполнения. Понятно, что оно все в байт-код транслируется перед исполнением, но может есть способ это обойти, или еще какие варианты?

Comment: eval ?  
Когда мне нужно было нечто подобное в php я сгенерированный код сохранял в файл, а его уже инклудил (import в питоне), а считать текст скрипта можно спокойно во время исполнения- это же обычный файл, Вы бы хоть попробовали :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных способов: по заданному объекту или методу найдите его код ([inspect.getsource](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)), постройте абстрактное синтаксическое дерево (`complier.compile` или `parse` до 2.6 или просто встроенная функция `compile` и `parse` в более новых версиях), видоизмените его на ваш вкус и выполните новый код. [Пример Марка Белмонта](http://blog.marcbelmont.com/2011/09/hacking-python-syntax-implicit-return.html)